# Horizontal brace above another brace + node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, pgf-decorations

In the following MWE, I've put a brace over the subordinate clause `that he knows` with a node `Subordinate clause` above the brace. Now I want to put a brace over the full sentence (the main clause) with a node `Main clause`. How do I position it above the already drawn brace + node? When uncommenting the commented code below, the new brace will be on the same horizontal line as the already existing brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (mainclause) {She said}; 
\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (subclause) {that he knows}; 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[decorate, decoration = brace] (subclause.north west) -- (subclause.north east)
            node [midway, above] {\footnotesize{Subordinate clause}};
%       \draw[decorate, decoration = brace] (mainclause.north west) -- (subclause.north east)
%           node [midway, above] {\footnotesize{Main clause}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you label the node containing the text `Subordinate clause` something like `subclauselabel`, then you can use the `intersections` library to find the intersection of perpendicular lines passing through your selected node anchors (e.g., vertical from `mainclause.north west` and horizontal from `subclauselabel.north.west`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}

\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (mainclause) {She said}; 
\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (subclause) {that he knows}; 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[decorate, decoration ={brace,raise=1pt}] (subclause.north west) -- (subclause.north east)
            node (subclauselabel) [midway, above=1pt] {\footnotesize{Subordinate clause}};
       \draw[decorate, decoration = brace] (mainclause.north west |- subclauselabel.north west) -- (subclauselabel.north east)
           node [midway, above] {\footnotesize{Main clause}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Quick question (I'll open a new question if it's not a quick thing): Do you know how I can adjust the distance between the brace and the ``that he knows`` clause? I would like it a little bit bigger. I can increase the distance between the labels and the braces by adding ``node [midway, above = 05.ex]``, but writing ``draw[decorate, decoration = brace, above = 0.5ex]`` has no effect.

Comment: You can change `decoration=brace` to `decoration={brace,raise=1pt}`. However, this will only move the brace and not the label. You may want to use `above=1pt` for the label as well. I'll modify my answer to show this.

Comment: @Sverre if you need to accentuate the brace `decoration={brace, transform={yscale=1.5}}` is one way of doing so. Perhaps changing the decoration amplitude is another.

Answer (score 6):

I've never really been a fan of the `remember picture` and `overlay` trick/kludge/workaround to get these kinds of effects. So, I am stubbornly sticking with the `text effects along path` decoration...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{%
  text as nodes/.style args={#1}{
    decoration={text effects along path, 
      text={#1},
      text effects/.cd, 
        path from text, text along path,
        group letters, word count=\w,
        every word/.style={name=word-\w, inner ysep=0.125ex},
    },
    decorate,
    insert path={(0,0)}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Create a sequence of nodes named word-1 to word-5
\path [text as nodes={She said that he knows}];

% Use the implicit perpendicular coordinate system:
\draw [decoration=brace, decorate] (word-3.west |- 0,0.5) -- (word-5.east |- 0,0.5)
   node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {Subordinate clause};

\draw [decoration=brace, decorate] (word-1.west |- 0,1) -- (word-5.east |- 0,1)
    node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {Main clause};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `text as nodes`.

Comment: @erik, well it only exists because I defined the `text as nodes` style in the answer. It is actually hiding a text decoration.

Comment: I see. In that case, good idea! I guess I should pay more attention to preamble code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Tikz by adding `calc` to the library list and modifying the brace coordinates (you can use any distancing method: cm, points, etc) for the Y axis. Here is a single coordinate example from below:

```
($(mainclause.north west) + (0,12pt)$)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=60pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (mainclause) {She said}; 
\tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (subclause) {that he knows}; 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[decorate, decoration = brace,above=2pt] (subclause.north west) -- (subclause.north east)
            node [midway, above=2pt] {\scriptsize{Subordinate clause}};
      \draw[decorate, decoration = brace] ($(mainclause.north west) + (0,12pt)$) -- ($(subclause.north east) + (0,12pt)$)
          node [midway, above, above=2pt] {\scriptsize{Main clause}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want use Tikz? You can obtain the results with a simple equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
$\overbrace{\text{She said}\overbrace{\text{that he knows}}^{\text{Subordinate clause}}}^{\text{Main clause}}$ et coetera...
\end{document}
```

And the results is:

[image: Results]

Comment: I'm not sure I have good reasons beyond these two: (1) I don't like using math environments for something that has nothing to do with math. (2) Those braces don't look very nice to me.

Comment: I'm agree with you about the braces; but I think this is a more compact way for obtaining the same result. About the environment: this is a your personal choice.